# jQuery - Etch-A-Sketch implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery

How could I make my code follow the **DRY principle?**
I feel like they are better ways to do things in my code. So any feedback will help me!

**js fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/fr6ut238/

```
    /*--------------------------- 
        Variables 
    ---------------------------*/
    const $containerGrid = $(".containerGrid");
    let boxSide = 16;

    const $gridLength = $("#gridLength");
    const $gradientButton = $("#gradient");
    const $randomButton = $("#random");
    const $resetButton = $("#reset");

    /*-- ------------------------- 
        Buttons & input
    ---------------------------*/
    $gridLength.on("input", gridLength);
    $gradientButton.on("click", incrementOpacity);
    $randomButton.on("click", getRandomColors);
    $resetButton.on("click", () => {
        reset(boxSide);
    });

    /*--------------------------- 
    Corresponding to Event listeners 
    ---------------------------*/
    function gridLength() {
        if (event.target.value !== 16) {
            reset(event.target.value);
        }
    }

    function incrementOpacity() {
        $(".cell").off("mouseenter");
        $(".cell").mouseenter((event) => {
            let opacity = parseFloat(event.target.style.opacity);
            if (opacity <= 0.9) {
                $(event.target).css({
                                    "opacity": `${opacity + 0.1}`,
                                    "backgroundColor": "#f5f5f5"});
            }
        });
    }

    function setRandomColors() {
        return Math.floor((Math.random() * 256));
    }

    function getRandomColors() {
        $(".cell").off("mouseenter");
        $(".cell").mouseenter((event) => {
            $(event.target).css({ 
                                "backgroundColor": `rgb(${setRandomColors()}, ${setRandomColors()}, ${setRandomColors()})`, 
                                "opacity": "1" })
        });
    }

    function reset(length) {
        boxSide = length;
        main();
        $(".cell").css({
                    "opacity": "0.1",
                    "border": "0.5px solid black",
                    "backgroundColor": "transparent"});
    }

    /*-- ------------------------- 
        Creates the Grid 
    ------------------------------*/
    function main() {
        $($containerGrid).empty();
        for (let row = 0; row < boxSide; row++) {
            for (let column = 0; column < boxSide; column++) {
                createCell();
            }
        }
        $(".cell").css("height", `${(300 / boxSide) - 1}px`);
        $(".cell").css("width", `${(300 / boxSide) - 1}px`);
    }

    function createCell() {
        const $cell = $('<div class="cell"></div>');
        $cell.css("opacity", "0.1");
        $containerGrid.append($cell);
    }

    main();
```

Comment: We need to know what your code is doing before we can review it. Please edit your question and explain the code's purpose.